# Leaking activity context when implementing exoplayer in a separate class

Tags: android, memory-leaks, out-of-memory, exoplayer2.x

I use the exoplayer 3 times in my application so I thought it would be better to implement it in its own class and just use it 3 times.

In doing this I introduced a memory leak so it is leaking the activity and causing the app to crash.

I am not really sure why this would be happening because I haven't closed the activity. I guess it is because there is some change in the activity or the view.

If you could tell me what is wrong with my implementation to cause a memory leak it would be greatly appreciated.

This is my exoplayer control class:

```
    public class ExoPlayerControls {

        Context context;
        SimpleExoPlayerView simpleExoplayerView;
        SimpleExoPlayer player;
        boolean preview;

        public ExoPlayerControls(Context context, SimpleExoPlayerView simpleExoplayerView, SimpleExoPlayer player, Boolean preview) {
            this.context = context;
            this.simpleExoplayerView = simpleExoplayerView;
            this.player = player;
            this.preview = preview;

        }

        public boolean setUPExoPlayer (String alarmMediaLocation){
            try {

                if (player != null){
                    player.setPlayWhenReady(false);
                    //URI location of audio
                    Uri mediaURI = Uri.parse(alarmMediaLocation);

                    // Data source Factory
                    DefaultHttpDataSourceFactory datasourceFactory = new DefaultHttpDataSourceFactory("alarm video");

                    // Extractor Factory
                    ExtractorsFactory extractorsFactory = new DefaultExtractorsFactory();

                    // Media source
                    MediaSource mediasource = new ExtractorMediaSource(mediaURI, datasourceFactory, extractorsFactory, null, null);

                    // Prepare the exoplayer
                    player.prepare(mediasource);

                    player.setPlayWhenReady(false);


                } else {

                    // Create a bandwith meter
                    BandwidthMeter bandwidthmeter = new DefaultBandwidthMeter();

                    // Create a track selector
                    TrackSelector trackselector = new DefaultTrackSelector(new AdaptiveTrackSelection.Factory(bandwidthmeter));

                    // Create the player
                    player = ExoPlayerFactory.newSimpleInstance(context, trackselector);

                    //URI location of audio
                    Uri mediaURI = Uri.parse(alarmMediaLocation);

                    // Data source Factory
                    DefaultHttpDataSourceFactory datasourceFactory = new DefaultHttpDataSourceFactory("alarm video");

                    // Extractor Factory
                    ExtractorsFactory extractorsFactory = new DefaultExtractorsFactory();

                    // Media source
                    MediaSource mediasource = new ExtractorMediaSource(mediaURI, datasourceFactory, extractorsFactory, null, null);

                    // Bind the player to the view.
                    simpleExoplayerView.setPlayer(player);

                    // Prepare the exoplayer
                    player.prepare(mediasource);

                    player.setPlayWhenReady(false);
                }


            } catch (Error e){
                Toast.makeText(context, "Exoplayer error" + e, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }

            return  true;
        }

        public void playAlarmMedia(String alarmMediaLocation){

            try {

                boolean exoPlayerSet = setUPExoPlayer(alarmMediaLocation);
                if (exoPlayerSet){
                    // Tell exoplayer to start playing immediately
                    player.setPlayWhenReady(true);
                }

            } catch (Error e){
                Toast.makeText(context, "Exoplayer error" + e, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }
}
```

And I implement it in my activity like this:

```
  // Initialise exoplayer controls
        exoPlayerControls = new ExoPlayerControls(this, simpleExoplayerView, player, preview);
        String alarmMediaLocation = downloadedAlarmToPlay.getAlarmMediaLocation();
        exoPlayerControls.setUPExoPlayer(alarmMediaLocation);
```

Comment: Check this https://github.com/google/ExoPlayer/issues/1855

Comment: Thanks. I read that earlier but it doesn't resolve the issue and it is not noted as bug from that discussion.

Comment: Should you not release the player when playpback is completed? 'player.release()'

Comment: The player uses system resources like codecs and uses memory for buffers.

Comment: Thanks. I understand that it uses resources but it is actually leaking the activity through the context.

Comment: There is a release in there,  I didn't include it because it is leaking before that is even needed to be called.

Comment: Did you try using getApplicationContext() instead of this in the activity?

Comment: The ExoPlayerControls has a reference to context which is used to create the player. So if you are reusing an instance of this class across activities it is leaking the context there? I don't think this is related to ExoPlayer but to the way the ExoPlayerControls works and is integrated in your app?

Answer (score 0):

The exoplayer class has three nested static classes/interfaces ExoplayerComponent, Factory and Listener. In general any Static objects will hold reference to an activity. Could the memory leak be caused by orientation changes? Because the activity will be unable to destroy itself. So older instances of the activity will be retained in memory causing a memory leak. A way to get over this is to use getAppplicationContext() instead of the Activity context (this). The application context is a singleton object. So every time Activity gets created due to screen rotation, no new instances of context are being created.